# Possible error in Stanley's combinatorics volume 1

Tags: combinatorics, limits, discrete-mathematics

Let $E(n)$ be the number of functions $f:[n]\to [n]$ without fixed points. An exercise (ex. 10 chapter 2) of Stanley combinatorics volume 1 asks to prove that $E(n)/n!\to 1/e$. But this seems blatantly false. Because clearly $E(n)=(n-1)^n$ and $(n-1)^n/n!\to \infty$. Did the author mean $E(n)/n^n$?

I'm uncertain because in the solution he insists on saying $E(n)/n!$.

Comment: Teacher is right.  See [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), especially the section "Growth of number of derangements as $~n~$ approaches $~\infty$".

Comment: *Clearly $E(n)=(n-1)^n$*... may not be so clear!

Comment: But I didn't say $f$ is a bijection, so I simply have $(n-1)$ choices for each element in the domain.

Comment: @Kandinskij No. This is true for the first element. But for the second element, you only have $n-2$ choices, and so on. To convince yourself, you can have a look at the case $n=3$.

Comment: @Kandinskij Sorry, I'm wrong. if $f$ is indeed not a bijection, then you're right. I imagine that $f$ is supposed to be bijective in the exercise.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net This is not possible. In the same exercise he uses $D(n)$ for derangements...

Comment: For both question and answers, it might help to emphasize bijectiveness and define $D(n)$ and $E(n)$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The exercise is false as printed, because $E(n)/n!\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Stanley must have meant $E(n)/n^n\to 1/e$. This makes sense, because the author makes a comparison to $D(n)/n!\to 1/e$. Both of the ratios $D(n)/n!$ and $E(n)/n^n$ are of the form
$$
\frac{\text{# things without fixed points}}{\text{# things total}}.
$$

Answer (score 25):

This is problem 10 in *Exercises for Chapter 2* in Volume 1, 2nd Ed. on page 222 of *[Enumerative Combinatorics](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/enumerative-combinatorics-vol-i)* by R. P. Stanley. In the *[Errata sheet](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/ec/errata_2ed.pdf)* the author states:

- page 222, Exercise 10(b), lines 1 and 2. Change $E(n)/n!$ to $E(n)/n^n$ (twice).

in accordance with OPs proposal and the nice answer from @MikeEarnest.

Comment: Good job finding the errata sheet. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Many thanks, but your answer is the *creative one*. :-) Nevertheless the main reason of my answer was to put the focus to errata sheets, which might be useful in general.

Answer (score 2):

This is Exercise 10(b) in Chapter 2. In the solution on page 269, you will find that "$E(n)/n!$" is replaced with $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/n}$, so indeed, it looks like $E(n)/n^n$ is what was meant.

Comment: Yes but it's still unclear because in the last line of the solution of the exercise he writes again $E(n)/n!$

Comment: This is obviously copied over from the above.

Comment: Just to clarify: when I wrote "this", I meant the second "$E(n)/n!$", as it was most likely copied from the first one just above during typing.